# How can I run an Octave file (.m) from C++ written in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, octave

My goal is to run an Octave file (an original .m script) from C++ written in Qt.

Currently, I am using Octave v7.1.0 on Windows 10, and the C++17 code is written in the Qt IDE v7.0.2. Additionally, my Build Environment has been edited to include mkoctfile.exe for compiling purposes.

I have followed the descriptions found from the Octave user manual in working with standalone programs, found here: [Standalone Programs](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Standalone-Programs.html). I can get the first matrix example problem working fine as shown with the following designed output

```
11:51:02: Starting C:\Users\berg\Documents\build-ForgeOctave-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\ForgeOctave.exe...
FTH: (2596): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
Hello Octave world!
 11 12
 21 22
11:51:02: C:\Users\berg\Documents\build-ForgeOctave-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\ForgeOctave.exe exited with code 0
```

, however the second example that requires the octave interpreter (which is needed for calling external Octave .m files per [Standalone Programs](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Standalone-Programs.html)) crashes with the following output:

```
11:54:52: Starting C:\Users\berg\Documents\build-ForgeOctave-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\ForgeOctave.exe...
FTH: (11156): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***
error: ignoring const execution_exception& while preparing to exit
error: ignoring const execution_exception& while preparing to exit
error encountered in Octave evaluator!
11:54:53: C:\Users\berg\Documents\build-ForgeOctave-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\ForgeOctave.exe exited with code 0
```

This leads me to believe that my issue is IDE-related. The exact issue that I am having at the moment, is when I call the Octave interpreter (octave::interpreter), it simply returns an error message of a crash.

My suspicion is that I may be missing a link to needed libraries or need to further edit my Build Environment or Build Steps.

Below is my .pro file.

```
TEMPLATE = app 
CONFIG += console c++17 
CONFIG -= app_bundle 
CONFIG += qt 
LIBS+= -L C:\Users\berg\Desktop\Octave\octave-7.1.0-w64\mingw64\bin -loctave-9 -LC:\Users\berg\Desktop\Octave\octave-7.1.0-w64\mingw64\lib\octave\7.1.0 -loctinterp -loctave 

SOURCES += \ 
        main.cpp 
 
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Octave-7.1.0\mingw64\include\octave-7.1.0\octave 
 
 
libmatrix.a
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this Octave interpreter problem or have suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You need to build your program using the `mkoctfile` program. You could add the `-v` option to learn the exact sequence of compile and link commands it executes, and which options and flags are passed to the compiler and linker, then attempt to recreate that in your own build environment.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I implemented the mkoctfile program in the Build Environment settings in Qt. Is this what you are referring to? I was able to build the first example problem just fine using mkoctfile. In order to call the octave::interpreter, do I need to make additional Build Environment edits?

Comment: I don't know what "I implemented the mkoctfile program in the Build Environment settings in Qt" means. The documentation page you link shows the command you need to give to build the program. That is how you build the program. To build one that additionally links to Qt or whatever, you'll have to add some compiler and linker flags for Qt. Conversely, you can use the Qt build environment, if you copy the compiler and linker flags that `mkoctfile` uses to build the program into your Qt compilation system. Do one of the the two.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I believe I got the `mkoctfile` step done correctly. However, I'm still having issues with the octave interpreter. My debugging process as shown that simply bringing in the interpreter (as in the second example of the previously linked source) with `octave::interpreter interpreter` causes my code to fail. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: I believe you didn’t get the `mkoctfile` step done correctly. If you had, things would work.

Comment: Type `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone standalone.cc -o standalone -v` at the command prompt. This will build the program, which should then work correctly. It should also print the compiler and linker commands issued. Examine those and see what compiler flags you are missing in your Qt build configuration. Likely you need some `-D` flag to enable stand-alone builds.